# Store Celery result as a hash in Redis

Tags: python, redis, celery

My idea is to fetch web-urls with JSON data in response and save this data into Redis DB, to have a fast in-memory access. And is seems that combination Celery-RabbitMQ-Redis looks very good for this case (i can use Redis as a broker also, but now it doesn't matter).
But using Redis as a backend, the results have the string type for values, and i want to save my JSON data as a hash. Can i change the format of result like 'id: json' and save it to Redis with hset? Or Redis as a backend cannot solve this task and it's better to save JSON data in Redis manually?

Comment: why you can't use `AsyncResult`? I mean, traditional way: `res = AsyncResult('task_id', app=app) if res.state
== 'SUCCESS' your_data = res.get()  # do something with data`.